# SpriteKit: Create rounded rectangle without using SKShapeNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Since there are memory/performance issues with SKShapeNode, is there a way to create rounded rectangles in SpriteKit without resorting to SKShapeNode? The question is for Swift, not Objective-C.

Comment: You don't just want to make an image in photoshop and link that up to a node? Or do you mean physics boundaries?

Comment: @BrennanAdler Because the size will vary, and so would like to create rounded rectangles dynamically as opposed to using fixed images.

Comment: Maybe try inputting an image of a rounded square and adjusting the size using xScale and yScale to make it different dimensions of rectangles?

Comment: @BrennanAdler xScale and yScale will blur the images though ...

Comment: Not if they are solid colored images, which I'm assuming he's doing something like that

Comment: If you change the `centerRect` property of the SKSpriteNode then when you scale it the rounded corners will not be scaled but the straight edges will. For more info check the docs.

Comment: As a response to your original question, you could use Core Graphics to create a CGPath for the rounded rectangle and draw this to a context and generate a texture. This will be slow if used too much. For more info do a search or check the core graphics docs.